# select 2 previous and 2 next records with one in between

Tags: mysql

Example:

```
ID  catID
1     3
2     2
3     3
4     1
5     3
6     3
7     3
8     1
9     3

select * from tbl where ID=5
```

How would I select records 1,3,6,7 ? Is this something that will take time, I mean a query/subquery?

Currently I select the whole set and then sort with a server script, thats why Im asking if its possible to select 5 records with mysql...or should I not bother

thanks

Comment: I don't understand your queestion at all. What is the pattern of rows you are trying to select? What have you tried?

Comment: select 2 previous and 2 next records with catID 3, what dont you understand? its a set of images

Comment: That's not what you asked. Don't get all snippy.

Comment: @BeavisIsCool: I don't understand what "2 previous and 2 next" records means. And that's not at all what you asked; your question says nothing about 'catID 3'.

Comment: Flimzy , when you check ids 1,3,6,7 - they are all catID 3, bingo.

Comment: Your question is not clear and thus far has required anyone who would help you to guess at your intention. Try thinking through it first, then rewrite your question.

Comment: @BeavisIsCool: If you want useful answers, it would behoove you not to be an ass to those trying to help you.  But have it your way. I'll go on to help someone who's grateful.

Comment: I think the question is answered by my second query. The question is not stated clear, but if I have interpreted it well, then is this what he wants.

Comment: Based on @LoekBergman's answer, I have a good idea what the OP is asking for... I also have a good idea how to answer the question. But my motivation to answer is lost.  Good luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your records are ordered by ID, you could use a query like this:

```
(SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE ID<5 AND catID=(SELECT catID FROM yourtable WHERE ID=5)
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE ID>5 AND catID=(SELECT catID FROM yourtable WHERE ID=5)
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT 2)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d636f/1).

Comment: I think you also need a `UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE ID=5`.  Or include that in one of your other queries (`ID<=5` or `ID>=5`)

Comment: yes, they ordered by id. Thanks a lot man, thats what I needed. Is this considered a slow query? Yes, Flimzy right, thats if I need record 5 in between as well.

Comment: @BeavisIsCool: How slow it is depends on far too many things to discuss here. How many rows are in your table, how your tables are indexed, what hardware you're using, what else your DB is using, which storage backend you're using, and a million other things. The only authoritative answer is: Try it and see how long it takes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tbl where catID = 3;
```

Is that the answer to the question you ask?

```
select *
from tbl
where  (0 < (id - x) and (id - x) <= 2)
    or (0 < (x - id) and (x - id) <= 2);
```

Comment: that will select all records, and if there are 100 records - too, I need only 5, but based on current ID (5) - two behind ID 5 and two after

Comment: Assuming 'x' is 2 in, this would only work if a) the target id was already known, and the target rows were all consecutive. I believe it would fail for the example the OP offered.

Comment: what is x in here? thanks for your answer , but i dont think it will work

Comment: It is the same idea as the correct answer, but that one is better, because it will select 2 rows no matter the actual values of the id's. x Is off course the variable 'unknown' and you might replace the value with 3 or 2 or whatever.

Comment: This solution is pure algebra, hence it works. It will even perform faster then the accepted solution. Which is however better, because it does not demand that the ids are consecutive. I advice you to not say that it will not work as long as you do not understand how it works.